# Mongodb 1 getting saved as 1.0

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

While running this query on a collection I am getting my expected value `1` is getting saved as `1.0`

```
db.getCollection('users').update({}, {$set: {isActive: 1}},
{upsert:true, multi:true})
```

Updated collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a31d14e358d0a5073f0ec26"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-14T01:18:06.784Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "isActive" : 1.0
}
```

Comment: If it is a problem, you can explicitly define data type, e.g.`{$set: {isActive: NumberInt(1)}` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/

Comment: @AlexBlex that solved my issue. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a problem, you can explicitly define data type, e.g.`{$set: {isActive: NumberInt(1)}`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types

Comment: Even if it solved my issue, shouldn't it be saved as only `1`? Is it an issue?

Comment: I don't see how it is an issue to be honest. If you search `find({isActive:1})` you still get documents with `"isActive":1.0`. But you asked - I answered, assuming this caused some problems in your particular case. Otherwise why would you bother to ask? =)

Comment: @niksmac JavaScript only has one [built-in numeric type](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp) (`Number`), which is always a 64-bit floating point value. If you work with numeric values in the `mongo` shell, 1 is still represented as a floating point unless you use MongoDB's helpers ([`NumberInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberint) for 32-bit integers or [`NumberDecimal`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#numberdecimal) for 128-bit decimal-based floating point values).

Comment: @Stennie thanks for the clarification. Appreciate it.